# Forcing cache update in browser

Tags: php, browser-cache, minify

I'm using Minify (https://code.google.com/p/minify/) to compress and combine ~30 css files and ~10 javascript files. I've created a group configuration for those files, which is basically an array with the filenames.

Works like a charm, except when one of the scripts is modified: browser cache is not timely update. I used to get a last modified timestamp for each file (using filemtime) to overrule browser caching:

```
$time = '?' . filemtime( $filename );
$output = '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="'.$file_path.'?'.$time.'" />';
```

I could loop through all 40 files to get the latest timestamp, but that is a very ugly solution. Another way would be e.g. to have a crobjob check it and write the timestamp to a file, which I can then include.

Any other ways before I'm inventing the wheel again?

Comment: You can use Cache-Control and Expires properties of php header by using a php handler and and redirect static file requests vi rewrite rule. See my answer for further detail

Answer (score 0):

can you not just add:

```
src="path/to/file.css?v=<?php date(dmy); ?>"
```

Comment: I could even add ?v=<?php time() ?> ;) But would prefer to use as much caching as possible.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I couldnt comment as the PHP tags kept editing out @nKn

Answer (score 0):

Just get the modification time of the `$file_path`...? Personally, I have a much more reasonable number of files (two or three) and each one is individually cached with its `mtime`. Works beautifully.

Comment: It's a modular system where each module has it's own css file; hence the 40 files.

Comment: My system's modular too, in that there's a core file and a file for each page of the site ;)

Comment: I used to have that too; now the files are combined, users get all css and js they need at first visit (which is the login page, so they don't notice a file loading in the background). Speeds up all other page loads :)

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you a way that you need to define a rewrite rule and implement a handler for static file load. Let say it is `assethandler.php`, and your rewrite rule;

```
RewriteRule ^nocache/(.*?)$ assethandler.php?f=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And in php you can use [Cache-Control and Expires](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php?#example-4559) for getting always latest file;

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 01 Jul 1990 05:00:00 GMT"); // past date
readfile('path_to_static_files/' . $_GET['f']);
```

and your static file requests will be like;

```
<script src="nocache/your.js"/>
```

Simply, when you make a request to `nocache/filename` this will be handled as `assethandler.php?f=filename` and in this handler, cache always disabled and file content served as latest content

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to completely disable caching.

Comment: This disable caching only when you use path `nocache/...`